# SQL Server stored procedure Text coming out in a weird manner..?

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

This is a weird question I guess, but I'm really facing this problem.

I have a SQL Server stored procedure compiled in my database server.

```
Create Procedure MyProc
As -- Start 
Begin
    Select 1
End
```

But when I run `exec MyProc`, I don't get any results!

Later I found out that there is something fishy in the stored procedure text.

I ran

```
sp_helptext MyProc
```

and saw to my surprise that, the procedure text is coming in this manner.

```
Create Proc MyProc As -- Start Begin Select 1 End
```

Whereas actually it should have come like this.

```
Create Proc MyProc 
As -- Start 
Begin 
    Select 1 
End
```

This is the reason why it's not getting me the results when I try to execute the stored proc.

Any solutions for this??

Comment: What happens if you just execute an `Alter Proc MyProc...` as how it should be?

Comment: What happens if you remove `-- Start`?

Comment: Can't reproduce this on SQL Server 2008 R2 - which **version** are you on??

Comment: Removing "-- Start", Using "/* Start */" solves the issue.
I'm using SQL Server 2005.
Is there any actual method for solving this issue, instead of these workarounds?? just curious....

Comment: How do you create the procedure? How do you obtain the result of `sp_helptext MyProc`? If it's in SSMS, is your *Results to* setting set as *Results to Grid* or *Results to Text* when you invoke `sp_helptext`? Could someone else accidentally spoil the definition? Do I ask too many questions?

Comment: How do you create your SP? What tool do you use? You will get this behavior if you don't have `CRLF` at the end of your lines. Only `LF` is not enough.

Comment: I've tried using Notepad++ to convert line endings to Windows (CRLF), Linux (LF), and Mac (CR) and the can't recreate the problem (the stored proc returns a result set) in all cases..

Comment: @TomHunter - Further testing on my part shows that a lacking `CR` will only recreate the behavior for executing `sp_helptext`. It will present the sp on one line (using "Results to Grid"). The SP itself will work just fine with a single `LF`. To recreate that the SP does not return any values at all you have to remove both `CR` and `LF`.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try as below, so far this would be helpful to you, thanks

```
Create Procedure MyProc
As -- Start 
Begin
    Select 1 as AliasColumnName
End
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried the same code in my system it works fine for me,but when i run sp_helptext MyProc it show separate rows for each line, try re-writing the procedure and use multiple return keys between the lines. tell me if it works.